# Erro google API

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to run the example code given by google and the following error appears:

```html
"message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

I created a credential and own client id, but I do not know where to insert in the code

código de exemplo:

```html
package javaapplication1;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;


public class JavaApplication1 {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
    String spreadsheetId = "1er12_Tp-m1IJNRfz-72VwVY14Gj10b-IexY60fzZiGg"; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
    String range = "a1:b4"; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // How values should be represented in the output.
    // The default render option is ValueRenderOption.FORMATTED_VALUE.
    String valueRenderOption = ""; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // How dates, times, and durations should be represented in the output.
    // This is ignored if value_render_option is
    // FORMATTED_VALUE.
    // The default dateTime render option is [DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER].
    String dateTimeRenderOption = ""; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Get request =
        sheetsService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range);
    request.setValueRenderOption(valueRenderOption);
    request.setDateTimeRenderOption(dateTimeRenderOption);

    ValueRange response = request.execute();

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    System.out.println(response);
  }

  public static Sheets createSheetsService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
    // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample
    //
    // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
    static Urlshortener newUrlshortener() {
  AppIdentityCredential credential =
      new AppIdentityCredential(Arrays.asList(UrlshortenerScopes.URLSHORTENER));
  return new Urlshortener.Builder(new UrlFetchTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
      .build();
}

    return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-SheetsSample/0.1")
        .build();
  }
}
```

the code is an example given by google, and I'm still learning, my only need is to read a spreadsheet from the google spreadsheet that has been filled up with forms answers from google

THanks

Comment: You would need to get an api key, please refer to this url https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Comment: I had already purchased this key, but the documentation does not show any code implementation examples. Basically I do not know what to do with this key.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java this has a full example, you would have to build GoogleClientSecrets  by providing the json you downloaded once you got the key.